# pySpark .join() with different column names and can't be hard coded before runtime

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I get this
`final = ta.join(tb, on=['ID'], how='left')`
both left an right have a 'ID' column of the same name.

And I get this
`final = ta.join(tb, ta.leftColName == tb.rightColName, how='left')`
The left & right column names are known before runtime so the column names can be hard coded.

But what if the left and right column names of the on predicate are different and are calculated/ derived by configuration variables? Such as:

`1) leftColName = 'leftKey'`

`2) rightColName = 'rightKey'`

`3) final = ta.join(tb, ta.leftColname == tb.rightColname, how='left')`

The values of `leftColName` & `rightColName` are not know before line 3 can be hardcoded and executed.

This doesn't work because I find runtime can intermittently get confused/lost in whether `rightColName` refers to `ta` or to `tb`

`final = ta.join(tb, f.col(leftColName) == f.col(rightColName), 'left')`

Scala appears to have a facility to enable this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are referencing the column as `ta.leftColname`, but - similarly to Pandas - you could also reference it by `ta["leftColname"]`.

This way, instead of a hardcoded column name, you can also use a variable. For example:

```
left_key = 'leftColname'
right_key = 'rightColname'
final = ta.join(tb, ta[left_key] == tb[right_key], how='left')
```

Comment: I swear I tried that. It threw an index must be a int cannot be a string error.  But now it appears to be working.  At least until it isn't again.  Thanks.
What else is different?  While awaiting your answer the cluster got a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If doing on multiple columns, then following list comprehension works

````
df1 = df10_fj.select(*(f.col(x).alias(x + "_df10") for x in df10_fj.columns))
df2 = df4_fj.select(*(f.col(x).alias(x + "_df4") for x in df4_fj.columns))

# df1, on=[df1.DOB_df10 == df2.DOB_df4, df1.soundex_lnm_df10 == df2.soundex_lnm_df4]

df = df2.join(df1, on=[df1[f"{c}_df10"] == df2[f"{c}_df4"] for c in join_cols])```
````